# Why can't i draw an image into a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, src

I've got a canvas and a div with scaled down images. I want to drag one of the scaled down images into the canvas. When an image is clicked on, the src should be saved so that if that image is dropped into the canvas, i gets drawn in the original scale. For some reason this code doesn't work...

HTML

```
<div id="LeftColumn">
    <canvas id="Canvas">
    </canvas>
</div>

<div id="TextureViewInside">
    <ul class="products">
        <img onclick="getSource(this.src)" id="firstPic" src="FärgadePapper.png">
            <img src="Hajar.png">
            <img src="Labyrint.png">
            <img src="Martini.png">
            <img src="FärgadePapper.png">
    </ul>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function first(){
    canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
}
function getSource(scr){
    alert(src);
    a = new image();
    a.src = src;
}
function dropped(){
    canvas.drawImage(a, 0, 0);
}
window.addEventListener("load", first, false);
```

Comment: Your markup with the `<ul>` around the images isn't really valid, if you care about stuff like that.  A `<ul>` element should have as children only `<li>` elements.

Comment: Also, you are probably getting errors in the console. You should always check that and include the errors in your SO questions.

Comment: i did but nothing came up. The plan is to be able to move the images around in the canvas with the mouse, any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Should be `new Image()`, not "image" with a lower-case "i". Also, you need to use the *context* and not the canvas directly to draw an image. Also in your `getSource()` function you called the parameter "scr" but the code in the function calls it "src".

Also you really should explicitly declare "a" somewhere.